# What does this python syntax mean?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I am not a python guy and I am trying to understand some python code. I wonder what the last line of below code does? Is that kind of multiple objects returned? or list of 3 objects returned?

```
req = SomeRequestBean()
req.setXXX(xxx)
req.YYY = int(yyy)

device,resp,fault = yield req          #<----- What does this mean ?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things going on in that line.  The easier one to explain is that the `yield` statement is returning a value which is a sequence, so the commas take values of the sequence and put them in the variables, much like this:

```
>>> def func():
...     return (1,2,3)
...
>>> a,b,c = func()
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Now, the `yield` statement is used to [create a generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators), which can return a number of values rather than just one, returning one value each time `yield` is used.  For example:

```
>>> def func():
...     for a in ['one','two','three']:
...         yield a
...
>>> g = func()
>>> g.next()
'one'
>>> g.next()
'two'
>>> g.next()
'three'
```

In effect, the function stops at the `yield` statement, waiting to be asked for the next value before carrying on.

In the example above `next()` gets the next value from the generator.  However, if we use `send()` instead we can send values back to the generator which are returned by the `yield` statement back in to the function:

```
>>> def func():
...     total = 0
...     while True:
...        add = yield total
...        total = total + add
...
>>> g = func()
>>> g.next()
0
>>> g.send(10)
10
>>> g.send(15)
25
```

Putting this all together we get:

```
>>> def func():
...     total = 0
...     while True:
...         x,y = yield total
...         total = total + (x * y)
...
>>> g = func()
>>> g.next()
0
>>> g.send([6,7])
42
```

A generator used in this way is [called a coroutine](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/).

Answer (score 4):

the last line is unpacking a tuple from the `send` method of the coroutine that the displayed code is located in.

that is to say that it occurs in a function:

```
def coroutine(*args):
    yield None
    req = SomeRequestBean()
    req.setXXX(xxx)
    req.YYY = int(yyy)

    device,resp,fault = yield req
```

there is then client code that somewhere that looks something like this.

```
co = coroutine(*args)
next(co)  # consume the first value so we can start sending.
co.send((device, resp, fault))
```

a simpler example of this that doesn't involve coroutines is something along the lines of

```
a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
```

or (slightly fancier)

```
for a, b in zip(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]):
    print a, b
```

here zip returns tuples that get unpacked to `a` and `b`. so one tuple would look like `('a', 1)` and then `a == 'a'` and `b == 1`.